# Adding comments to MS Word tables

Tags: vba, comments

I'm trying to add comments to the table rows. the idea is that you select a table and the macro would add a comment to every row.

say you have a string followed by an integer in the comment content.

example comment content would be :

```
comment1
comment2
comment3
```

Note that the contents of the comments are important , as they play a vital role.

Here is what I got so far , if some one has already got this figured out , please help me out

```
Sub CallAddNewComment()
    Dim i As Integer

    i = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count


    Do Until (i > 1)
        Call AddNewComment(strText:="This is a test comment.")
    Loop

End Sub

Sub AddNewComment(ByVal strText As String)

   Comments.Add Row = i, Text:=strText

End Sub
```

Comment: You must improve your formatting!

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do.  Should the code automatically create a different comment for each row?  What part of the row should the comment be attached to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim tbl As Table, i As Long

    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For i = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
            ActiveDocument.Comments.Add _
                   tbl.Rows(i).Cells(1).Range, "Comment" & i
        Next i
    Next tbl

End Sub
```